# Chrome does not follow proxy rules

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, dns, hostname

I'm sitting behind a proxy server, which gives me a configuration and routing rules via a .pac file (configured in the global internet settings in windows).
There are some URLs that should not be routed to the proxy server, as they are local addresses in our company. There is also a rule to not route localhost. For development purposes, I have given my machine an alias hostname: *127.0.0.1 dev.company.com*

Accessing the URL *dev.company.com:8080/index.html* with Internet Explorer or Firefox gives me the expected result, however, the same URL in Chrome gets routed to the proxy server, which (of course) is unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run: chrome://net-internals/proxyservice.init_log#proxy in your chrome browser and re-apply your settings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't even know about that tool. The refresh itself didn't help, but it did lead me to this page: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/debugging-net-proxy

It works fine in Internet Explorer, but fails in Chrome -> 
As an experiment you can try running Chrome with the command-line flag --winhttp-proxy-resolver